# How to remove unwanted quotes from JSON data ?

Tags: php, json

When I try to json encode an array using static value it output like :

```
[
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,5],"name":"www.google.com"},
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,4],"name":"www.yahoo.com"},
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,85,0],"name":"www.bing.com"}
]
```

then I tried json encode using dynamic value  it output like this

```
[
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,"5"],"name":"www.google.com"},
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,"4"],"name":"www.yahoo.com"},
  {"data":[0,0,0,0,"85",0],"name":"www.bing.com"}
]
```

for non-zero value, there a extra double quotes ("") how remove it  ?

Comment: Looks like you're saving the dynamic value to a string instead of a number?  Why don't you convert it before or after?

Comment: tanx bro..., it works great

Answer (score 4):

You need parse with **intval**, example:

```
$arr = array("1", intval("2"));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Outputs:

```
["1",2]
```